# How can I setup multiple unit test engines in 1 arcconfig?

Tags: arcanist

I am trying to add multiple test engines in arcconfig and I tried adding it like an array to .arcconfig but unit.engine takes only strings.

"unit.engine": ["MochaTestEngine", "KarmaTestEngine"]

Does it have to be another MultipleTestEngine wrapper that runs both of the above or could it be specified elsewhere as an array?

Answer (score 0):

This might come handy: https://github.com/bitnami/arcanist-extensions#multi_test_engine

Bitmani team has made the one already.

From the official docs:

**Installation**

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/bitnami/arcanist-extensions.git .arcanist-extensions
$ git submodule update --init
```

**Integration**

```
// .arcconfig
{
  "load": [
    ".arcanist-extensions/rspec_test_engine",
    ".arcanist-extensions/multi_test_engine"
  ],

  "unit.engine": "MultiTestEngine",
  "unit.engine.multi-test.engines": ["MochaTestEngine", "KarmaTestEngine"]
}
```